# Upload 100mb SVG file to server with Javascript

Tags: javascript, svg, encoding, base64, image-uploading

I am developing image edit software based on Javascript and Java( Servelets backend). Currently, I can perform my task without any issue by Javascript( fabric js and sencha ext js).

Issue :
 IF I added some big images and SVG files total final output file size get increased. Currently, I using Base64 encoding method to send the data to the server.
* While converting the canvas SVG file to base64 string, browser consumes huge amount for memory for a larger design.

Browser failed most of the time is the design file is bigger than 50mb.

1. What is the best way to send my data to the server?
2. What is the "Advantage" and "Disadvantage" of encoding files(my canvas SVG files. Design final output may contain text, other SVG files and images. sensitive data can be contained) before sending to the server. ?

Comment: make the data smaller. 50mb is not a reasonable size for a browser to work with.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. In this time I couldn't control the size of SVG output. Most of the time size will be 30mb but some user like create complex design. Then the output SVG file size will be increased.

Comment: Display an error and ask the user to provide a simplified file.